# If statement instantly true without printf

Tags: c

I have noticed that if I put a `printf` statement, the code works the way I expect (waiting 5 seconds before if statement is true). But if I don't put the `printf` in the loop, the `if` statement is true instantly. I want to know why this is?

```
int main()
{
    int i;

    for(i=0; i<10000000; i++){
        int ticks = clock();
        int time = (float)ticks / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
        printf("%d \n", time); //If this printf statement is not here

        if(time >= 5){ //This will become true immediately
            break;
        }
    }

    printf("\nTimer is done");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Unable to reproduce, statement in question seems implausible. Possible compiler might be optimizing the entire loop out if it has no observable effects.

Comment: Seems good to me. Show us a screenshot of your error.

Comment: Calling `clock` is observable behaviour. Or it would be if the right header were included

Comment: http://prntscr.com/esl0e4 Without printf http://prntscr.com/esl0ht with printf

Comment: <time.h> was included

Comment: Please post your real code. This code should fail to compile, as `CLOCKS_PER_SEC` is not defined.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/esl0ve This is proof its the real code add <time.h>

Comment: `time` might have reached 5 and you have no idea it already reached 5. try inserting your `printf` inside the `if` block

Comment: same problem still hits the if statement instatly

Comment: what is the output of `printf("%d \n", time)` inside your `if` block?

Answer (score 1):

You are using `int` where you should have been using `time_t`. `int` can potentially overflow in this context leading to undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how fast your computer is, the loop without the print may take less than a second to run 10 million times, so may seem to exit 'instantly' (it takes about a second and a half on my averageish 2 yr old desktop).

If you want an infinite loop, use `while(1)` or `for(;;)`

Answer (score 0):

1. *clock();* returns the amount of time spent in your program.
2. *CLOCKS_PER_SEC* This macro expands to an expression representing the
   number of clock ticks per second.

Now as @Chris_Dodd said, your CPU is very fast. So **time will immediately reach the value 5.**